# How to change a game's setting to enable a dedicated graphics card?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

I have only *one* video game that refuses to let me select the Nvidia Graphics Card. Some background:
I recently got a new laptop (Lenovo Y50), and I have downloaded a ton of games off of my Steam account. I had to set some settings initially, but after a restart all of my games got their default settings to be the dedicated card. All of them except one. That one is *Naruto Ultimate Ninja Storm 3: Full Burst*. The game absolutely refuses to select the dedicated card, no matter what I've tried. I've tried setting the "global" setting to the dedicated card-- no dice. I can't change the game's settings from within the Nvidia Control Panel:
[http://i.imgur.com/Jb8xLo1.png](https://i.imgur.com/Jb8xLo1.png)

And whenever I go to run it from the folder it's housed in, it says the dedicated card is selected but it still runs off of the integrated card!

[http://i.imgur.com/OI3fvzJ.png](https://i.imgur.com/OI3fvzJ.png)

I've tried everything I could think of, save messing with the BIOS (which I don't want to do, because this game did run on the dedicated card before!). Any tips? How can I get this game to recognize the dedicated card? I can't choose the graphics card from in game, there is no setting/option for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just bought the Y50 too, pretty sweet huh. Aite so I just solved the problem.

First of all, update your drivers to the latest one. Next, get Nvidia Inpector. Open the program, click the little wrench button and in profiles (top bar) look for the naruto game. Then delete it, (press the red cross). Idk how but this seems to work for me.